# Quiero lograr que al realizar el Login se muestre automáticamente los datos del usuario en el siguiente Fragment

Tags: android

Lo que pasa es que para poder ver los datos del usuario necesito ingresar el código del usuario "rut" y luego dar click al botón "buscar" para que me aparezcan sus datos. Lo que busco es que los datos aparezcan automáticamente al ingresar con el Login. Espero me puedan ayudar, saludos y gracias!

Este es el código del fragment que quiero arreglar

---

```
private void cargarWebService() {
        pDialog=new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        pDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
        pDialog.show();

        final String ip="http://192.168.1.5";

        String url=ip+"/ejemploBDRemota/wsJSONConsultarUsuarioUrl.php?rut="+txtRut.getText().toString();

        jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                pDialog.hide();

                Usuario miUsuario= new Usuario();

                JSONArray json=response.optJSONArray("usuario");
                JSONObject jsonObject=null;

                try {
                    jsonObject=json.getJSONObject(0);
                    miUsuario.setNombre(jsonObject.optString("nombre"));
                    miUsuario.setApellido(jsonObject.optString("apellido"));
                    miUsuario.setCorreo(jsonObject.optString("correo"));
                    miUsuario.setPas(jsonObject.optString("pas"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                etiNombre.setText(miUsuario.getNombre());//SE MODIFICA
                etiApellido.setText(miUsuario.getApellido());//SE MODIFICA
                etiCorreo.setText(miUsuario.getCorreo());//SE MODIFICA
                etiPas.setText(miUsuario.getPas());//SE MODIFICA

            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se puede conectar "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println();
                pDialog.hide();
                Log.d("ERROR: ", error.toString());
            }
        });

        request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        VolleySingleton.getIntanciaVolley(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Has realizado algo?, agregalo a tu pregunta para evitar sea cerrada, saludos!

Comment: @YorchSircam ahora agregue información sobre lo que quiero modificar, gracias amigo!